# ASP.NET MVC2 garbage in urls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

We have a strange issue where Google's webmaster tools is alerting us to some rather strange URLs that it is attempting to spider. We don't have a clue where these are being generated and would like to understand how they were ever created. These are of the form:

http://test.xyz/(F(pC3Rt9u0AmQepAH-uY341LtzYEKrdkOOEgB9nDyfdDB6X9uL__MmT7S-euwfO_yPKKz8gdhnBhv8v1aGkuRj6G61sSaQ7mo1F8-PI32-pZxh9UJjogZk9Shvp7jdTaFLGHLEEw0_TtMNfvgoNMg6iQhOenxOisfvYc0BfbtxM53ksFvR0))/funk-radio

Usually this would take the form:

http://test.xyz/funk-radio

but asp.net MVC seems to deal with the garbage (by ignoring it?) and it appears that the (first) request gets routed correctly. In fact it seems that all routes work correctly when this garbage is added. For instance:

http://test.xyz/some/other/page

is equally reachable via:

http://test.xyz/(F(pC3Rt9u0AmQepAH-uY341LtzYEKrdkOOEgB9nDyfdDB6X9uL__MmT7S-euwfO_yPKKz8gdhnBhv8v1aGkuRj6G61sSaQ7mo1F8-PI32-pZxh9UJjogZk9Shvp7jdTaFLGHLEEw0_TtMNfvgoNMg6iQhOenxOisfvYc0BfbtxM53ksFvR0))/some/other/page

This implies to me that the garbage has some sort of special meaning. Can anyone enlighten me as to what's going on here. These routes should not match, yet clearly they do. What's going on?

EDIT

We're not using cookiless auth. Here's the relevant part of the `web.config`:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" defaultUrl="~" slidingExpiration="true"
        timeout="10080"/>
</authentication>
```

Interestingly, if I connect to the site with the standard user-agent:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0`,

using one of these garbage filled URLs then the request is honoured.

If on the other hand, I connect using the googlebot UA

`Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)`

I get a 400 response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the urls the first things that come to mind is that your site is using authentication without cookies. When I worked with ASP.NET, for a project we used authentication cookiless and the framework put that token before every url.

Comment: Certainly explains why the token might be ignored, but we do not have cookieless auth enabled, so I'm still drawing a blank as to how that URL was generated in the first place. I've updated my question to reflect this additional info. If I disable cookies and try to log in, the garbage does not get created. Log in simply fails (silently).

Comment: look at the sessionstate tag: something like that <sessionState mode="InProc" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlConnectionString="data source=127.0.0.1;user id=sa;password=" cookieless="true" timeout="20"/>

Comment: it also could be something like `cookieless="auto"`. I do not remember the exact syntax, but the meaning is 'detect if client support cookies and use them, if possible'.

Comment: There are no sessionState tags in our web.config, so we're just using default settings. We use session (very) occasionally, but switching off cookies does not cause the strange token to be generated when using session or authentication. Hmmmmm....

Comment: Also, strangely, the urls work fine from my dev machine, but from my colleague's machine, they cause HTTP 400 errors. Google also sees them as HTTP 400. I will get a firebug session open to establish what differences (if any) exist.

Comment: Well AFAIK if you use or not session, the session is always created. So this should explain why you get the token without explicitly using the session. If it's not here the problem I can not think of anything else ATM. Sorry

Comment: Could also be in the forms authentication config.  Adding cookieless="UseCookies" will fix this.